# How do you tell what object is being touched in touchesBegan?

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uitouch, touchesbegan

I know that this is a very commonly asked question, but all of the answers on every website don't work!  If you still don't know what I mean, then maybe this line of code will help you understand.

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:self.view];
    if (touch.view == nextbutton)
        [self performSelector:@selector(next)];
    if (touch.view == prevbutton)
        [self performSelector:@selector(previous)];
    if (touch.view == moreoptionsbutton)
        [self performSelector:@selector(moresettings)];
}
```

It doesn't do anything when you touch `nextbutton, prevbutton, and more optionsbutton`, which are `UIImageViews` by the way. I have also tried using `isEqual:` instead of `==`, but that hasn't worked out either.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You have to set userinteractionEnabled = YES for all your UIImageViews otherwise they will not receive touch events. Also change the line:

```
 UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
```

to

```
 UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
```

Comment: Thank you for the userinteractionEnabled = YES tip. I was banging my head to figure out why my UIImageView was not registering touches.

Answer (score 2):

I created a check to be sure its the view I expect to be clicked before going on.

```
if( [touch.view isKindOfClass:[Custom class]] ){
    CGPoint touchPoint = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if( CGRectContainsPoint( self.customClassOne.frame, touchPoint )
       || CGRectContainsPoint( self.customClassTwo.frame, touchPoint ) ){
        [self touchOnCustomClass];
    }
}
```